# Regex for extracting space separated string value between brackets

Tags: regex, grafana

I am trying to extract strings separated by empty space between square bracket as below

**Issue Background:**
I am trying the below scenario in my Grafana dashboard for creating variables for one of my dashboards by connecting to Mongo datasource. As part of mongo query execution, I will be getting the below said values always([Microservice_1 Microservice_2 Microservice_3]) where the number of values inside square brackets may vary. Also these values are always separated by empty space

**Original**:

```
[Microservice_1 Microservice_2  Microservice_3]
```

**Expected:**

```
Microservice_1
Microservice_2
Microservice_3
```

I have tried `\[(.*?)\]` but I am not getting expected result

Comment: umm, do you need to explicitly capture the square brackets?

Comment: What language are you using? You can slice and split the string instead of using regex; for example: `string.slice(1, -1).split(' ')` (JS), `string[1:-1].split()` (Python), etc.

Comment: You need to add more input samples and expected output. Else in your current case, just split them using `[\[\s\]]+` to get your desired results.

Comment: Consider just to use `\w+`

Comment: @BagusTesa No. I like to omit square brackets in my case and I need only the values inside it.

Comment: @InSync I am using this regex pattern in Grafana. In my case, I am getting the above said result as part of MongoDB query. To use these obtained value as variable in Grafana dashboard, I am trying to extract using regex pattern

Comment: I would capture every non-closing bracket instead: `\[([^\]]+)\]`. This does not work if you have brackets within brackets.

Comment: @PatNowak Tried with \w+ but it is not working for my case.

Comment: @PeterKrebs   This regex pattern(\[([^\]]+)\]) removes square bracket but not splitting the values

Comment: You can't do it with a single regex in Grafana.

Comment: @Naina *"I am using this regex pattern in Grafana"* - this sounds like [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). you should have told us the use case (e.g. being used in a query to filter stuff) rather than partial problem like this. the reason i asked was there are many ways to solve this.. including ignoring the square brackets as PatNowak suggested or use string splitting function as InSync said. furthermore, regex has many implementations and each have their own caveats.

Answer (score 0):

Grafana's regex cannot split values. It can only extract a single value from the original string: if you need to produce three output values, you'll need to supply three input strings.

I belive in this case the best approach will be to split values in the data sources side.

Consider using something like [`$split`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) in your query.